# How do you apply performance tuning settings for Native zfs?

Tags: performance, zfs

I am currently running an Ubuntu 12.10 Desktop with some zfs pools. I have installed ZFS using the following instructions and from the PPA it contains:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZFS

I have a bursty/fluctuating write performance issue which is apparently a known issue. I have found several posts where people have the exact same problem. Constant fluctuating writes. According to the http://wiki.freebsd.org/ZFSTuningGuide I need to apply some settings to "avoid the bursty IO that's often seen with ZFS." This must be done in the /boot/loader.conf.

Since Ubuntu does not use that, as far as I can tell, I have no idea how to apply settings like:

```
vfs.zfs.prefetch_disable="1"
vfs.zfs.txg.timeout="5"
kern.maxvnodes=250000
vfs.zfs.write_limit_override=1073741824
vfs.zfs.arc_min="512M"
vfs.zfs.arc_max="1536M"
vm.kmem_size_max="8G"
vm.kmem_size="6G"
```

Which is mentioned in the general tuning section. Other sources say use sysctl. But when I do I get this:
sudo sysctl vfs.zfs.prefetch_disable="1" 
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/vfs/zfs/prefetch_disable: No such file or directory

I cannot find anything for vfs or zfs in /proc/sys.

Where does one do this kind of thing in Ubuntu?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The option is already set by default in most zfs-fuse packages.  Double check that this is in the `/etc/zfs/zfsrc` file:

```
# zfs-prefetch-disable : disable zfs high level prefetch cache
# This setting can eat as much as 150 Mb of ram, so uncomment if you want
# to save some ram and are ready to loose a little speed.
zfs-prefetch-disable
```

Alternatively, to set this option for the native ZoL driver, do this:

```
# modprobe zfs zfs_prefetch_disable=1
```

To make the change permanent, create a `/etc/modprobe.d/zfs` file and put this line in it:

```
options zfs zfs_prefetch_disable=1
```

Most tunable parameters for ZFS on Linux are set through module options.  You can get a full list of available options by running this command:

```
# modinfo zfs
```

Most of these options will correspond directly to things that can go in the `loader.conf` or `sysctl` on other systems.

Comment: sudo modprobe zfs
FATAL: Module zfs not found.
I realise now that this is not a fuse implementation.  I installed Native ZFS. Sorry I have updated the question correctly. Your options do not work in this case.

Comment: "Module not found" means that Native ZFS is not installed or incompletely configured.  Run `dkms status`.  You should see something like `zfs, 0.6.0.90, 3.2.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed`.

Comment: No such module. The ZFS PPA does not seem to install ZFS as a module.

Comment: The ZFS PPA do install ZFS as a module. Install kernel headers, and then run dpkg-reconfigure. That way, DKMS compiles and installs the module. Also, if you have new problem, post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You can find more settings in `/sys/module/zfs/parameters`

For exmaple:

```
$ cat /sys/module/zfs/parameters/zfs_prefetch_disable
0
$ echo 1 >/sys/module/zfs/parameters/zfs_prefetch_disable
```